# Unpivot data in table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unpivot

My source is like

```
**Col1  Col2 Col3  Col4    Col5  Col6**
1     ABC  STAT1  STAT2  COM1  COM2
```

How do I get below

```
**Col1 Col2 type Col4   Col5**
1    ABC  STAT STAT1  STAT2
1    ABC  COM  COM1   COM2
```

I looked at Unpivot, its able to do one column -> one row . But I'm looking for 2 columns into 1 row. Union all would be one option, but I would like to see it using unpivot

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method is a lateral join, but that is not available until Oracle 12c.  If you have only two options and your table is not really big, `union all` is probably sufficient:

```
select col1, col2, 'STAT' as type, col3 as col4, col4 as col5
from t
union all
select col1, col2, 'COM' as type, col5, col6
from t;
```

If scanning the table twice is a performance issue, there are other options as well.

A pretty simple way without `unpivot` is a `join`:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, tt.type,
       (case when tt.type = 'STAT' then col3 else col5 end),
       (case when tt.type = 'STAT' then col4 else col6 end)
from t cross join
     (select 'STAT' as type from dual union all
      select 'COM' as type from dual
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.Over the period this table will get bigger. So im interested to use built in process like unpivot so that I dont need to visit this in future for tuning